# How do I overlay a transparent image on a swiper and still be able to swipe?

Tags: css, swiper.js

I have an iPad image with a transparent background so that the swiper images are within it.

Codepen [here](https://codepen.io/magician11/pen/qNZqep?editors=0100).

The issue I'm having is that when I have the iPad image *outside* of the `swiper-container` div, it looks great, but I can no longer click on the images in the swiper to move/swipe them..

```
   <div class="swiper-container image-slider">
      <div class="swiper-wrapper">
        <div class="swiper-slide">
          <img src="https://unsplash.it/300/400/?random" />
        </div>
        <div class="swiper-slide">
          <img src="https://unsplash.it/300/420/?random" />
        </div>
        <div class="swiper-slide">
          <img src="https://unsplash.it/300/410/?random" />
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <img class="ipad-frame" src="https://www.dropbox.com/s/2ehll1khqxw7nxl/ipad_isolated_no_bg.png?raw=1" />
  </div>
```

When I put it the iPad image *inside* the `swiper-container` div it works great, but it doesn't overlap the images as I need it to. The swiper-container crops it.

```
<div class="swiper-container image-slider">
  <div class="swiper-wrapper">
    <div class="swiper-slide">
      <img src="https://unsplash.it/300/400/?random" />
    </div>
    <div class="swiper-slide">
      <img src="https://unsplash.it/300/420/?random" />
    </div>
    <div class="swiper-slide">
      <img src="https://unsplash.it/300/410/?random" />
    </div>
  </div>
  <img class="ipad-frame" src="https://www.dropbox.com/s/2ehll1khqxw7nxl/ipad_isolated_no_bg.png?raw=1" />
</div>
```

Any ideas on how to wrap the `image-slider` with the iPad transparent background while still being able to swipe the images?

Comment: try adding `pointer-events: none;` for `.ipad-frame`

Comment: Can you use any other jq plugin for swipe? if yes i have solution.

Comment: @Vitorinofernandes perfect! Thank you. Would you like to add it as an answer below?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Adding `pointer-events: none;` for `.ipad-frame` will allow to swipe the image